# Rspec Controller test not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My controller and my test file are bellow.

controllers/reports_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @reports = Report.all
  end
```

specs/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:

```
RSpec.describe ReportsController, type: :controller do
  let(:test_report) {
    2.times.map {
      create(:report, student: create(:student), report_options_attributes: [
        {option: create(:option), note: "ole" }
      ])
    }
  }

  describe "GET #index" do
    before(:each) do
      get :index
    end

    it "should be success" do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it "should render index template" do
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end

    it "should load all reports" do
      expect(assigns(:report)).to match_array test_report
    end
  end
```

The last test is not working, but it should work. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

index test is empty..you need to assert something to pass.

can you add.. `assert_response :success` in index function.

Comment: The first two tests are passing. Just the last one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your var is different from the controller. Use reports instead of report like this:

```
it "should load all reports" do
      expect(assigns(:reports)).to match_array test_report
    end
```

It should work.